A short story about a writer compelled to write lest he drown in ink
I read this short story more than 30 years ago, in a collection of Fantasy and SF. It is not SF so it must be fantasy.
It is about a writer who used to be prolific but now has failed to give his editor what the latter is expecting. So, since it must be Fantasy, IIRC, the editor got help from some imp, or demon or whatever. Otherwise there would be no Fantasy aspect at all.
Anyway the writer is now locked in a room with ink constantly flowing into it. His only way to keep from drowning is to keep writing, very fast, in order to use more ink than what flows in. This is totally ridiculous since however fast his imagination allows him to write, doodling would be faster, to say nothing of dropping paper directly into the ink to absorb it.
But the way the author writes it is better than my synopsis, and it really gives an amusing story.
EDIT
As mentioned in the comments, the writer probably was a Fantasy-SF writer, but I am not 100% sure.

Do you recall if the writer in the story was a writer of science fiction and fantasy?

Did it feel like a very old story, perhaps written when authors commonly wrote with pen and ink?

@user14111 I think the writer was indeed in the field of SF&F. As for writing in pen and ink, that was the situation he was put in. I don't think the context was so old that old-fashioned ribbon typewriters did not exist. But probably old enough that these were the only typewriters (and not available to the writer in his prison.) I mean, there were editors of SF&F magazines.

@user14111 When I think about it, the way I visualided the pen was the kind I used in junior high. Ball-pen were not allowed and we used pens which contained ink in as mall compartment, that had to be regularly refilled by using a little pump. I read the story imagining that the only way the writer could decrease the amount of ink was by refilling his pen. (When these torturous things was replaced pen using by ink in little plastic containers one could easily replace when they were empty, it was a great liberation).

Many SF stories about SF writers are liisted at the Recursive Science Fiction site. Searching that site for the word "ink" I didn't find anything that looked like your story, but maybe I missed something. If the story were written by the likes of Asimov I'm sure someone would have identified it by now, so I guess it's by some less famous writer.

@user14111 I looked at all the stories in that site by Asimov, including the one with J.S. Hudson that also involves compulsive writing but none is mine. So either it is not by Asimov, or it is by him, but the writer is nor SF&F. But stories about "mainstream" writers are not listed anywhere, are they ?

@user14111 I was able to find on your site all the stories by Asimov, but I did not find how to search the site for a specific word. How did you do it ?

One way would be to use site:https://data.nesfa.org/Recursion/ ink in a Google search. Another would be to do a Ctrl-F search on each of the 23 A-Z pages at that site. Maye it's also possible to download their database; I don't know about that.

@user14111 I followed your advice and looked for "ink" and "drown" on each of the 23 pages to no avail. Asimov or not is irrelevant : the "writer" must be a mainstream (or maybe crime mysteries, or some other genre) but not SF&F.

I wouldn't draw that conclusion. The Recursive SF site has collected many such stories, but I bet they are still missing quite a few.

@user14111 I still have not found my story. My bounty is about to expire. I want to thank you for your efforts. Do offer an answer, any answer at all, so I can give it to you to thank you for your efforts rather than see 50 reputations go down the drain. They are out of my account anyway....

Sorry but I can't think of a plausible answer to your question. Having 50 reputation points vanish from the system is hardly a tragedy, since new points are being created all the time. If it bothers you, you should stick to offering "bounties that don't expire" which avoid that problem. As for this question, surely it's better for it to remain as an "unanswered question" instead of giving in a wrong answer.

@user14111 I was definitely not considering accepting a wrong answer during the 7 regular days of the bounty. I was considering "manually awarding" the bounty to a "non accepted" answer during the "grace period" of one day that follows, as I have done on multiple occasions before.  But the notion of "bounty that does not expire" is interesting. How do I do that ? I'd appreciate a link to the explanation. Thanks in advance.

I was about to add a link to my previous comment but then I noticed that you had already offered a "bounty with no deadline" so I thought it was unnecessary. Here is the link: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12517/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadlines

@user14111 The other times, there was already at least one answer, which was not the story I was looking for but that did show some efforts so I gave the bounty without accepting the answer, and without asking the user whose answer I thanked.

@user14111 Thank you for the link, but I did not do anything. How come my bounty became a "bounty with no deadline" I have no idea !!

You posted this "answer' to that meta question on May 29: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12517/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadlines/14091#14091

@user14111 Oh yes I did ! I completely forgot ! I thought you meant this bounty here. So I did find the trick, and forgot it. Thanks for reminding me !

Of course, if you had a perfect memory, you wouldn't be posting story-ID questions!

@user14111 ROTFLOL !
